# Using aria-sort in validated HTML5

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c-validation, wai-aria

Assuming a static HTML table, such as:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" aria-sort="none"><a href="...">Name&#xA0;<span title="Sort">&#9650;</span></a></th>
            <th scope="col" aria-sort="ascending"><a href="...">Score&#xA0;<span title="Ascending">&#9650;</span></a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Would the use of `aria-sort` be appropriate (for when UA's that support it)?

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-sort

I believe this could be useful, but the W3C validator currently requires a `role="columnheader"` on the `<th scope="col">`, which is kind of redundant, as it already implies a `th[scope="col"]`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#columnheader

And once you start specifying that, you also need to set a role for everything up to the `<table role="grid">`... which is fine if your not using appropriate tags.

Comment: I would say 1- this is an appropriate use of `aria-sort`, and 2- I would agree with your assertion and say this would be a bug in the validator

Comment: Looks like this might already be a known issue: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-cvs/2014May/0000.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The validator is correct. This may sound odd, but the problem is in the specifications, not in the validator.

As @CraigFrancis comments, this issue has been raised in the validator’s mailing list, where a message refers to a bug report. The bug has been [closed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-cvs/2014May/0001.html) on the grounds that the validator’s behavior is correct, as per the specifications. This means that if you use [`aria-sort`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-sort), you need to explicitly set `role` to `columnheader` or `rowheader`, even if you have the `scope` attribute.

As the question states, this means that additional `role` attributes are then needed higher up in the document tree , so that you minimally end up with the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>aria-sort issue</title>
<table role="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none"><a href="...">Name&#xA0;<span title="Sort">&#9650;</span></a></th>
            <th scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="ascending"><a href="...">Score&#xA0;<span title="Ascending">&#9650;</span></a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This looks rather redundant, especially since the definition of [`role=columnheader`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles#columnheader) says that it is “the structural equivalent to an HTML `th` element with a column scope”. However, HTML5 LC [definitions related to WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#wai-aria) do not specify any implied ARIA semantics for `th` (or `tr` or `table`). This might reflect the use of tables for layout, which has been widespread, so that it is unrealistic to assume in general that a `table` element represents a grid (array, matrix) in the structural (or “semantic”) sense. Thus, when the “tabularity” of a `table` element is relevant to ARIA, it must be explicitly expressed with `role` attributes at different levels of nesting.

Note that the `aria-sort` attribute is purely informative, declarative. It *describes* that the items of a table (grid) *are* in ascending or descending (or other) order. It does not ask the browser to sort them or to create UI tools for sorting. In practice, it is meant to be used when the author has taken care of sorting the table, in page generationg server-side or with JavaScript client-side. User agents can make use of this information in various ways, e.g. by announcing the user about the order.

The ARIA specification adds that “For each table or grid, authors SHOULD apply `aria-sort` to only one header at a time”. The code example violates this recommendation. (No error message is issued, however, by the validator; this is SHOULD, not a SHALL.) In this case, `aria-sort="none"` should be removed. The `aria-sort` attribute, when set on a column header, specifies that the rows of the table are sorted according to that column, so for obvious reasons it should be set on one column only.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, that's very useful information... so we will need to pester the HTML working group, as I believe a <table> should hold tabular data by default (inheriting the "grid" role by default), and any website that uses tables for layout should really be using role="presentation" as an override (knowing full well that is wishful thinking).

Comment: 2020 update: You do _not_ need the roles (nor the scope attribute in this case). Support has improved greatly since this answer was provided.